# Replace the browser full url

Tags: javascript, browser

It's possible to replace the browser url included the domain? I've tested `history.pushState('data to be passed', 'Title', 'test');` but thaat not replace the domain.

Comment: well you can do `window.location.href="http://www.example.com"` but you are not going to keep the page where you are at.

Comment: Not without redirecting the page, pretty sure that would open up a security issue otherwise. As a site could pretend to be a bank site and then change the url at the top to be the bank's domain url without actually changing the page.

Comment: Tis its the problem I don't want a redirection,only update the browser url

Comment: That is spoofing a URL.... You can not make a page look like it is not on a doamin that it is on. Think of the problems if a hacker makes a page look like a bank, gmail, etc.... Not going to happen.

Comment: if you are trying to spoof, just popup a blocking alert. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace the domain of the page that you are on. Are you trying to redirect? If so, you can use this to change the page:

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
```